# What does a return value of -1 mean in a regular expression search

Tags: javascript

I am using a regular expression to check for a 4 digit number but in my code `==-1` is used and I'm confused with how it works. I thought the alert would pop up when anything less than 4 digit gets entered in the input box but it also comes up when I enter in more than 4 digit numbers. I would like to know the logic behind

```
function checkpostal(){
  var re4digit=/^\d{4}$/ //regular expression defining a 4digit number between beginning and end value

  if (document.myform.myinput.value.search(re4digit)==-1) //if match failed
    alert("Please enter in a 4 digit number");
}
```

Comment: Just a note. `.test` would be better for repel checking.

Comment: If successful, search() returns the index of the first match of the regular expression inside the string. Otherwise, it returns -1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Answer (score 0):

When testing your regex pattern in Chrome's console I got the following results:

```
> "1233334".search(/^\d{4}$/)
-1
> "124".search(/^\d{4}$/)
-1
> "124444".search(/^\d{4}$/)
-1
> "4444".search(/^\d{4}$/)
0
> "44444".search(/^\d{4}$/)
-1
```

-1 Indicates that the expression you're looking for was not found in the string you're testing your regex against.

Your regex query is searching the string you're testing against for something that is *exactly* 4 digits long. This means that when you test against something that is greater than or less than 4 digits then the .search(r4digit) will return -1.

This is similar to Javascript's String.prototype.indexOf function which also returns -1 when no substring is found; it's just a simple way of saying the search went all the way to the end and found nothing.

Comment: Could you explain on why it shows -1. Why doesn't it show 0?

Comment: `.search` and `.indexOf` return the location in the string. If it isn't I the string it will say it is at `-1` because 0 is where Strings / Arrays start